# Type of object returned by object.Create

Tags: javascript

I am trying to grasp certain concepts of Javascript. Here is small situation

```
// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.info('Shape moved.');
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
}

// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype)
```

Now, if I type

```
Rectangle.prototype instanceof Shape
true
```

Now, does it mean the **type** of the object **returned by** `Object.create` (in my last line of first code snippet), is `Shape`? It seems yes. Though I didn't request it anywhere, I just specified the prototype of that object which should be same as `Shape.prototype`.

I just can't find this documented in the `Object.create` docs. Can someone explain if this is the case and (maybe also) **why** that is the case?

**Extra**: Also, it seems by using line

```
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype)
```

I am inheriting methods, and not the instance variables declared in the `Shape` constructor? Because prototype doesn't know anything about the properties specified inside the `Shape` constructor? e.g. `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean the type of the object returned by `Object.create` (in my last line of first code snippet), is `Shape`?

No. There is no `Shape` type. ECMAScript only has these types: Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, String, Symbol, Object.

The value returned by `Object.create` belongs to the Object type.

> I just specified the prototype of that object which should be same as `Shape.prototype`.

Yes, and that's exactly what you got. `Object.create` returns a new non-callable ordinary object whose [[Prototype]] is the argument.

The `instanceof` operator, by default, only checks the prototypical chain, that is, property inheritance. It does not ensure that the supposedly instance really was constructed by the constructor.

Comment: Yeah but then why is Rectangle.prototype instanceof Shape true?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava It seems you expect `o instanceof C` to check something different. It just checks that `C.prototype` appears in the prototypical chain of `o`. So it's expected.

Comment: Also can you elaborate on what  non callable object means?

Comment: An object `obj` is non-callable if it does not have a [[Call]] internal method, so `obj()` will throw something like `TypeError: obj is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  // Shape - superclass
  function Shape() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
  }

  // superclass method
  Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
    outputArea.innerHTML += '<br>Shape moved.';
  };

  // Rectangle - subclass
  function Rectangle() {
    Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
  }

    // subclass extends superclass
  Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype)
  
  var outputArea = document.getElementById("output");
  
  // Shape doesn't inherit from Shape:
  outputArea.innerHTML += "<br>Shape instance of Shape: " + (Shape instanceof Shape);
  
  // Shape is a constructor function and functions inherit from Object:
  outputArea.innerHTML += "<br>Shape instance of Object: " + (Shape instanceof Object);  
  outputArea.innerHTML += "<br>Shape.prototype is: " + typeof Shape.prototype;
 
  // Rectangle isn't an instance - it's a constructor function:
  outputArea.innerHTML += "<br>Rectangle instance of Shape: " + (Rectangle instanceof Shape);
  
  // But, Rectangle's prototype is an actual instance of Shape:
  outputArea.innerHTML += "<br>Rectangle.prototype instance of Shape: " + (Rectangle.prototype instanceof Shape);
  
  // But, if we make an instance of Rectangle...
  var r = new Rectangle();
  
  // Shape's constructor will be called (executed) with the new Rectangle object instance serving as the "this" object.
  
  // r IS an instance of Rectangle which IS an instance of Shape:
  outputArea.innerHTML += "<br>r instance of Shape: " + (r instanceof Shape);
  
  // Use the inherited methods that use the instance fields:
  r.move(10,20);
  outputArea.innerHTML += "<br>r.x = " + r.x;
  outputArea.innerHTML += "<br>r.y = " + r.y;

});
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

When you wrote:

```
 // subclass extends superclass
 Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype)
```

You are asking for the object that `Rectangle` inherits from to be a new object that is of the same type as `Shape`'s prototype. Thus, Rectangle has inherited everything that Shape has defined for it and therefore a `Rectangle` is an instance of a `Shape`.

`Object.create(obj)` returns a new instance of an object with that instance's prototype set to the type of object that you passed into the `create()` method. This is how inheritance is established and if one object inherits from another, it can be said that that object is an instance of the other.

Comment: "Object.create(obj) returns a new instance of an object with that instance's prototype set to the type of object that you passed into the create() method" --> This I understand. But what about the type of the object returned by Object.create(obj)? (Basically your first paragraph isn't that clear to me, unlike second one)

Comment: The type is the same as the prototype's type. So, `Object,create(widget)` returns a new object that has its prototype set to an instance of a `widget`. It has then inherited from `widget` and is an "instance of" `widget`.

Comment: Shape.prototype instanceof Shape --> gives false

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava You are confusing `typeof` with `instanceof`. In JavaScript, the prototype object is an actual INSTANCE of a type. Shape's prototype is not Shape, it's Object. An INSTANCE of Shape, will have a prototype of Shape.

Comment: Seems we are on different pages, I basically asked why Rectangle.prototype  instenceof Shape yields true

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava And, I answered that. You need to explore prototypes and prototypical inheritance more.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava I have added a code snippet with comments to my answer. If you run through it, it should help, but this is considered an advanced topic in JavaScript and it is one that take time and practice with.

Comment: Thanks but you can have a look at the final comment from zerkms -- basically that is the info I was missing ;)

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava That's exactly what I wrote in the last paragraph of my answer.  "Object.create(obj) returns a new instance of an object with that instance's prototype set to the type of object that you passed into the create() method. This is how inheritance is established and if one object inherits from another, it can be said that that object is an instance of the other."

Comment: What was unclear to me was that type of object is determined by type of prototype as said by zerkms. Anyway, thanks for the effort +1.